Would a small foam sponge in a 2.5 inch enclosure damaged the flat flex cable on a HDD?
I have an Orico enclosure case model 25PW1 and a Seagate ST500LM030 HDD.
The case contains a small foam sponge. I think its material is EVA and the manual says to place this small foam sponge in the lower part of the case but this small foam sponge is in direct contact with the lower part of the HDD and the exposed flat cable.
Will the pressure between the small foam sponge and the HDD damage the HDD flat cable in the long term or is it safe?




unless the disk starts rattling around, and it damages the sata/power connector solder joints

I don't think any company would sell a enclosure that would damage a HDD.
I suspect the sponge is there to isolate the HDD from the case and reduce vibrations. Practically, unless you had something pokey (to use the scientific term), or you somehow 'peeled' or pulled a flat flex able or solder joint, there's going to be no damage. Gentle, wide area pressure won't do damage to a  solder joint or flat flex cable.
I also suspect (there's no manual) that the drive's floating a little over the base of the case, that the main mechanical connection is via the SATA connector and this foam pad is sized to support, not apply pressure on the HDD in use.
Its also likely to be non-conductive so you wouldn't see any shorts.
